# Realloc with an array of pointers in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, realloc

In C89, the following code works fine :

```
typedef struct{
    int size;
    int **ptr;
}foo;

int main()
{
    foo *var;

    var = malloc(sizeof(foo) + 2 * sizeof(int*));

    int a = 3, b = 6;

    var->ptr[0] = &a;
    var->ptr[1] = &b;

    printf("%d %d\n", (*var->ptr[0]), (*var->ptr[1]));

    return 0;
}
```

When executed it shows : 3 6

But if I replace

```
var = malloc(sizeof(foo) + 2 * sizeof(int*));
```

with

```
var = malloc(sizeof(foo));
var = realloc(var, sizeof(foo) + 2 * sizeof(int*));
```

It compiles without any warning but I get a segmentation fault at the following line :

```
var->ptr[0] = &a;
```

I really have no idea what I am doing wrong so I would appreciate any input. I'm a beginner so I apologize if my mistake is obvious.

Thank you.

Comment: You never initialize the `ptr` field.

Comment: @DevSolar: Well, actually he DOES allocate memory for `ptr` (that is what the `+ 2 * sizeof(int*)` is for), he just doesn't assign `ptr` to point at that memory

Comment: both versions are wrong, the first one exhibited a particularly bad form of Undefined Behaviour - it appeared to work fine

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Do you want a single continuous block of memory for that struct, including the array of ints. Or do you just want that struct pointing to the array

Comment: I wonder why newbies post their questions and then don't stick around to answer any questions that come up by people trying to help them.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood It's been less than a day since I posted this so not sure why you would say that... unless that was more of a general statement not directed towards me.

Comment: @pm100 I want a struct with an array of pointers to int as well as a variable indicating to how many int the array points to. If I understand correctly, my ptr variable needs to be declared like this : int **ptr and not like this : int *ptr[] otherwise I wouldn't be able to do dynamic memory allocation. I completely understand my mistake now about not initializing the ptr field. Thanks

Comment: @SparklingFire: Welcome to Stackoverflow. For best results, you'll want to stick around immediately after posting a question because it will never get as much attention as it will at that time.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood I see, thanks for the advice, I wasn't expecting to get answers that quickly to be honest, I guess this is a really active place :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this is also wrong in C89.

```
malloc(sizeof(foo) + 2 * sizeof(int*));
```

is allocating more than you need it, but not in the way you expect.

```
+-------+------------+---------+--------+
|  size | ptr        |  int*   | int*   |
+-------+------------+---------+--------+

|  sizeof foo        | 2 * sizeof(int*) |
```

As you see, `var->foo` is still uninitialized, no matter how many extra bytes
you've allocated, so

```
var->ptr[0] = &a;
var->ptr[1] = &b;
```

is going to fail.

What you should have done is:

```
var = malloc(sizeof *var);

var->ptr = malloc(2 * sizeof *var->ptr);

var->ptr[0] = &a;
var->ptr[1] = &b;
```

Then it would look like this

```
                                     | int |     | int |

                                     +-----+     +-----+
                                     |  a  |     |  b  |
                                     +-----+     +-----+
                                         ^         ^
                                         |         |
                                         |         |
+-------+------------+  points to     +---------+--------+
|  size | ptr        | ------------>  | int*    | int*   |
+-------+------------+                +---------+--------+

|  sizeof foo        |                | 2 * sizeof(int*) |
```

Don't forget to check for the return value of `malloc` and to free the memory
afterwards.

**edit**

what would work is:

```
var = malloc(sizeof(foo) + 2 * sizeof(int*));
var->ptr = (int**) ( ((char*) var) + sizeof *var );
```

where you set `var->pointer` to point past the memory for the `struct`. While
this might work, I think it's pretty ugly, I would reject a commit of a
co-worker with something like this.

Comment: Thanks, very clear answer. For some reason, I thought I couldn't directly use malloc on a variable inside a struct but I was obviously mistaken. Thanks to everyone who answered, many answers were also useful although some didn't seem to realize that I wanted to store the adresses of a and b and not their values.

Answer (score 5):

I think your declarations are wrong. The following line assumes that `ptr` points to some memory when in fact it has not been initialized at all!

```
var->ptr[0] = &a;
```

If your compiler supports it, shouldn't it be more like this instead:

```
typedef struct{
    int size;
    int* ptr[0];
}foo;
```

Otherwise, change `ptr[0]` to `ptr[1]`, and adjust your calculations based on the fact that the structure already includes one element.

*Note: Once you write to a wrong address, the result is undefined. You have a problem there but it only happens to show up in one case. The problem is still there in both cases.*

Comment: you should note that his code is storing the address of a not the value of a.

Comment: @pm100: Right you are.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not assigning `ptr` to point at anything, so it points to random memory, and any access of `ptr[index]` is **undefined behavior**.

Changing the declaration of `ptr` like Jonathan's answer suggested is the safest option, eg:

```
typedef struct{
    int size;
    int* ptr[1]; // or 0 if your compiler supports it
}foo;

int main()
{
    foo *var;

    var = malloc(offsetof(foo, ptr));
    if (var) {
        var->size = 0;
        ...
    }

    foo *newvar = realloc(var, offsetof(foo, ptr) + (2 * sizeof(int*)));
    if (newvar) {
        var = newvar;
        var->size = 2;

        int a = 3, b = 6;

        var->ptr[0] = &a; // <-- OK!
        var->ptr[1] = &b; // <-- OK!

        printf("%d %d\n", *(var->ptr[0]), *(var->ptr[1]));
    }

    free(var);
    return 0;
}
```

But, if for whatever reason, you can't change the declaration of `ptr` (`foo` is used with an existing API, for instance), then you can do this instead:

```
typedef struct{
    int size;
    int **ptr;
}foo;

int main()
{
    foo *var = malloc(sizeof(foo));
    if (var) {
        var->size = 0;
        var->ptr = NULL; // <-- add this!
        ...
    }

    foo *newvar = realloc(var, sizeof(foo) + (2 * sizeof(int*)));
    if (newvar) {
        var = newvar;
        var->size = 2;
        var->ptr = (int**)(var + 1); // <-- add this!

        int a = 3, b = 6;

        var->ptr[0] = &a; // <-- OK!
        var->ptr[1] = &b; // <-- OK!

        printf("%d %d\n", *(var->ptr[0]), *(var->ptr[1]));
    }

    free(var);
    return 0;
}
```

In this latter case, make sure you do the same `ptr` assignment every time you want to (re)allocate `var`.  I would wrap that logic in a set of helper functions, eg:

```
typedef struct{
    int size;
    int **ptr;
}foo;

foo* createFoo(int size)
{
    foo *var = malloc(sizeof(foo) + (size * sizeof(int*)));
    if (var) {
        var->size = size;
        var->ptr = (int**)(var + 1);
    }
    return var;
}

foo* resizeFoo(foo **var, int newSize)
{
    foo *newvar = realloc(*var, sizeof(foo) + (newSize * sizeof(int*)));
    if (newvar) {
        newvar->size = newSize;
        newvar->ptr = (int**)(newvar + 1);
        *var = newvar;
    }
    return newvar;
}

int main()
{
    foo *var = createFoo(0);
    ...

    if (resizeFoo(&var, 2)) {
        int a = 3, b = 6;

        var->ptr[0] = &a; // <-- OK!
        var->ptr[1] = &b; // <-- OK!

        printf("%d %d\n", *(var->ptr[0]), *(var->ptr[1]));
    }

    free(var);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int size;
    int *ptr;
}foo;
```

And the code:

```
 var = malloc(sizeof(foo));
 var->ptr = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));

 int a = 3, b = 6;
 // store a and b in array, not their addresses
 var->ptr[0] = a;
 var->ptr[1] = b;
```

Assuming you want 2 entries in the array. And of course, ignoring the fact that I am not testing the result of `malloc()`.

If you want to resize the array, just realloc `var->ptr` instead of `var`.

Comment: because he doesnt know what he's doing - we should ask him :-)

Comment: i doubt you did that , he is storing the address of local variables in that struct. I asked - lets see what he says

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, Windows 10, both of your examples doesn't work. This is because the struct is uninitialized in both situations.

The arrow operation:

```
foo->bar
```

is a shorthand write for:

```
(*foo).bar
```

Therefore, if "foo" struct variable is uninitialized, depending on the compiler, the pointer inside your struct will point to a random location in memory.

So, when you used the arrow operator as such:

```
var->ptr[0] = &a;
```

What you did was:

```
(*var).ptr[0] = &a;
```

So, basically, you tried to write the address of "a", into a location in memory, that you shouldn't have accessed. This is why you are getting a segmentation fault.

However, if you instead have initialized it:

```
int goodmemorylocation = 0;
var->ptr = &goodmemorylocation; // You change the location of your pointer to an accessible location in memory
```

Then your code works for both cases, in my system.

Perhaps, in your system, the first example that you used malloc, somehow points to a correct address in your memory. This is why it works.